# Using tabs to navigate screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

The tabs page have three tabs- Nearby,Recent and Notice tabs.

```
Tabs.dart-
class Tabs extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(width: 24),
        MyTab(text: 'Nearby', isSelected: false),
        MyTab(text: 'Recent', isSelected: true),
        MyTab(text: 'Notice', isSelected: false),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final bool isSelected;

  const MyTab({Key key, @required this.isSelected, @required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: isSelected ? 16 : 14,
              color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
              fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.w600 : FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 6,
            width: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              color: isSelected ? Color(0xFFFF5A1D) : Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the home-page.dart file the tabs defined in tabs.dart file is called but are non-functional -

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Header(),
                SizedBox(height: 40),
                Tabs(),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                SlidingCardsView(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see that the `SlidingCardsView()` is called below the tabs, but I want to open the `SlidingCardsView()` on clicking the recent tab and further `PageOne()` to Nearby and `PageTwo()` to notice tabs. Can anyone help me with this?.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here is the code, change things according to your needs further,

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Tabs(refresh: () => setState(() {})),
            value == 0 ? Center(child: Text("Nearby Page", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 56))) : Container(),
            value == 1 ? Center(child: Text("Recent Page", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 56))) : Container(),
            value == 2 ? Center(child: Text("Notice Page", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 56))) : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function refresh;

  Tabs({this.refresh});

  @override
  _TabsState createState() => _TabsState();
}

int value = 1;

class _TabsState extends State<Tabs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(width: 24),
        MyTab(text: 'Nearby', isSelected: value == 0, onTap: () => _updateValue(0)),
        MyTab(text: 'Recent', isSelected: value == 1, onTap: () => _updateValue(1)),
        MyTab(text: 'Notice', isSelected: value == 2, onTap: () => _updateValue(2)),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _updateValue(int newValue) {
    widget.refresh();
    setState(() {
      value = newValue;
    });
  }
}

class MyTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Function onTap;

  const MyTab({Key key, @required this.isSelected, @required this.text, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: isSelected ? 16 : 14,
                color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.w600 : FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 6,
              width: 20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                color: isSelected ? Color(0xFFFF5A1D) : Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```